# How can I share from OneDrive without giving out my mobile number?

Tags: onedrive

I've just signed up to Office 365 (Home) and a OneDrive account. I'm trying to share a folder of documents so that another user can edit anything in that folder.

Although when I started I seem to have managed to share a couple of test files as read-only, every time I try now I get a message that sharing is temporarily blocked. To unblock, it wants my mobile number to send an authorisation text.

I don't want to give my mobile number to Microsoft! Is there another way to unblock this?

Answer (score -1):

I found [Why is my account temporarily blocked](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/sign-in-account-temporarily-blocked-ui) from Microsoft Support.

Not exactly helpful but it does confirm that Microsoft are the ones asking for your mobile number (not some scammers). Still mystified as to why! Email would be a lot safer.

Comment: Please add essential part of the link in your answer.

Comment: No, email would not be a lot safer. If your Microsoft Account is compromised, the attacker more than likely has access to your email. It's unlikely that someone who's hacked your password _also_ has your cell phone.